# Pattern checking for validating a phone number

Tags: perl

I have written a regex for validating a phone number, but there is something wrong I dont know what.
Required:

1. Leading '011' country code, this can be in parenthesis or without paranethesis
2. 1-3 digit country code
3. 2 digit city code
4. a code in form of `ddd-dddd` for local phone number(3 digits dash then 4 digits)

Legitimate separators for the groups are dash(-) and spaces.
Eg: `(011) 23 55 345-9878` or `011-3-33-987-6543`.

Here is what I have tried:

```
if($_ =~ /^:?([011]:?){1}[ -]+[0-9]\d{2}+[ -]+[0-9]\d{2}+[0-9]\d{3}-[0-9]\d{4}/){
    say "Line5 Good: ", $currLine;
} else {
    say "Error in Line 5: Not a valid phone number ";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This regex tests out OK - feel free to season it to taste:

`(\(011\)|^011)([ |-])\d?\d?\d([ |-])\d{2}([ |-])\d{3}([ |-])\d{4}`

`(\(011\)|^011)` ensures only (011) or 011 will be accepted at the beginning of the number, so there should be no worries about all the other permutations like )011, 011), etc, creeping in. The rest takes care of your desired formatting. I may have went a little over board on either|or but I simply find groups easier to read...

You can test it for yourself here: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?36s51

Cheers to Roberto Navarro turning me on to gskinner.com.

Answer (score 0):

This should be the regex: `\(?011\)?[ -]\d?\d?\d?[ -]\d{2}[ -]\d{3}[ -]\d{4}`

Validated here on: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ but I didn't find a way to send you the link.

Screenshot :) BTW, the blue highlight indicates a match, so in this case, all your conditions matched. Typo in screenshot, it should say, "Failed match more the 3 country code"

[image]

Comment: it also matches an opening parentheses without the corresponding close - http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?36s4l

Comment: OK, what about this: (\(011\)|011)[ -]\d?\d?\d?[ -]\d{2}[ -]\d{3}[ -]\d{4}